# Getting random stack overflows from Gembox Spreadsheets .NET

Tags: .net, excel, stack-overflow, spreadsheet, gembox-spreadsheet

I've been using Gembox.Spreadsheets for a few months now and it've worked just perfectly throughout the time. Recently though, the program crashes due to stack overflows in the library, which I ofcourse can't control. The overflows are pretty weird, they don't happen in places they "should" instead it's at things like:

```
floorStyle.FillPattern.SetSolid(Color.LightGray);
```

I tried commenting out the above code but then it did a stack overflow at some other place instead.

This leads me to believe there's something else wrong. Note that I can not debug this at all in VS2012, it just crashes with an exception.

Today I found out that my collegue had accidently shut down the Windows 7 laptop during the "configurating..." phase of windows update, on shutdown. It had apparantly gone wumbo jumbo but seems to work just fine. This event seems to have taken place just by the time the stack overflow's started happening, is it related?

I do not use any recursive code at all, and the program is single-threaded.

Now my questions is:

- If it's related, how can I recover from a messed up update configuration? I've tried to do a system restore but there's no point available before the event.
- Is there any alternative spreadsheet library I can use? It doesn't have to support Excel files but it's a plus. Printing is my only priority

Comment: Were you able to log the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: The only thing I get is "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occured in Unknown Module".   Note that I'm using VS Express if it's any difference.

Comment: If you are debugging at the time, open the "Call Stack" panel. It will show you the full call stack (ie. which methods were called by which). You should be able to identify a loop in the method calls and track down the problem.

Comment: The call stack is empty, VS also tells me "No Source Available: The current thread is not currently running code or the call stack could not be obtained"

Answer (score 0):

You should [contact GemBox support](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/support-center/new-ticket) and provide a VS test project that reproduces the issue.

Without investigating the problem, stack trace, etc... it's impossible to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Pretty sure I read that they don't provide support for free copies

Comment: They do, it's just that free users have a lower priority then professional users.